# Showing only contacts who have an account created in the app from a database value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-contacts

Hello I have a problem that I have been trying to solve for a long time and without success.

I am creating a whatsapp style APP. And as such, I would like it to appear in my Users Fragment, the contacts saved in the user's mobile phone contact list. To do this I created a reference in the database (**phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode**) that will fetch each user's mobile phone number and then compare it with the contact list.

The code I made available shows all registered users and this is something I wanted to change as I mentioned.

For lack of sufficient knowledge at this point, I'm stuck on this.

Thanks for your help right now.

**My Firebase Database:**

- **Users** is the row where all personal information of each user is stored.
- Then comes a row representing the **User Id** of each user.
- Then comes the user information (there is more obviously but I didn't enter it because I don't think it's relevant beyond that).
- **Name** is the username that should be displayed in the Users Fragment. That is different from the name of the contact in the contact list.
- **phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode** is the non-Country Code mobile number obtained from EditText when you first log in with your mobile number.
- **uid** is the user ID.

```
    {
      "Users" : {
        "Bakpv8gs6keE95nFrRz4jnXOqka2" : {
          "name" : "User 1",
          "phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode" : "123789456",
          "uid" : "Bakpv8gs6keE95nFrRz4jnXOqka2"
        },
        "ET2PD26FpweYHIdPYtdlF1KDQEZ2" : {
          "name" : "User 2",
          "phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode" : "987654321",
          "uid" : "ET2PD26FpweYHIdPYtdlF1KDQEZ2"
        },
        "JGqx9sZ6nZOAmaQmpruuxowvsps1" : {
          "name" : "User 3",
          "phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode" : "123456789",
          "uid" : "JGqx9sZ6nZOAmaQmpruuxowvsps1"
        }
      }
    }
```

**This is the code from my Users Fragment that need to be changed:**

```
private void getAllUsers() {
    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //get path of database named ""Users" containing users info
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    //get all data from path
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelUser modelUser = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);

                //get all users except currently signed in user
                if (!modelUser.getUid().equals(fUser.getUid())){
                    userList.add(modelUser);
                }

                //adapter
                adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(getActivity(), userList);
                //set adapter to recycler view
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Users Fragment looks like this:** [Screenshot](https://scontent.fopo2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/82215214_2452805188303159_6180327268858986496_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=RMNmI4p3IwQAX_95r6f&_nc_ht=scontent.fopo2-1.fna&oh=b2e0119e1a6fd2367ead07beb9c2e163&oe=5E9E635F)

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Plus: you can simply remove the values you don't want to share. :)

Comment: "and then compare it with the contact list" maybe show us that part of your code as well

Comment: WOW! Thank you for that! I had never seen this option. ahahah

Comment: Ok.Updated code and added information.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 450 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: OK. Updated now. Thx.